# Google Calendar API: Disabling alerts for Apple Calendar synced to Google Calendar

Tags: calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api, icalendar, google-api-python-client

I'm using the Google Calendar API with the Google Python client library to create a calendar and events in a user's Google Calendar. The events that I'm creating are intended to be a like a to do list, so they are all-day events and shouldn't have alert notifications. I'm creating an event like this:

```
event = {
  'summary': summary,
  'start': {
    'date': start_date
  },
  'end': {
    'date': end_date
  },
  'reminders': {
    'useDefault':False
  }
}
```

I'm using `reminders.useDefault` to disable alerts on the Google Calendar. The problem is that I have a Apple Calendar (iCal) synced to Google Calendar and in the Apple Calendar app, those events do have alerts enabled by default and I get spammed with the alerts of the dozens of events I create for each day. Is there a way to turn off the corresponding alerts in the Apple Calendar synced with the Google Calendar using the Google API, or is this strictly in the domain of Apple's Calendar app?

Answer (score 0):

To disable reminders, you should set useDefault=false and add empty override reminder section.

Comment: According to the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert): "If the event doesn't use the default reminders, this lists the reminders specific to the event, or, if not set, indicates that no reminders are set for this event". So not setting the `reminders.overrides` should result in no reminders set. I also went ahead and tried adding `'overrides':[]`, but it didn't have any effect in Apple Calendar.

Comment: You really need to set useDefaults=false for the overrides section to apply at all.

Comment: To clarify, I'm am setting `useDefault` to False and `overrides` to an empty array, and those aren't impacting the Apple Calendar notifications.